# Using the same dbcontext for different models

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a DbContext that is empty. Mappings are created dynamically and the DbContext is used generically using Set();

The following is my generic DbContext.

```
/// <summary>
/// Object context
/// </summary>
public class MethodObjectContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;

    public MethodObjectContext(string nameOrConnectionString, IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    public MethodObjectContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection, IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _eventPublisher.Publish(new ModelCreating(modelBuilder));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

I am trying write a unit test that will assert that the database is out of sync if I change the mappings (from the ModelCreating event).

The following is my test code.

```
[TestClass]
public class MigrationTests
{
    private string _connectionString = string.Empty;
    private string _testDb = string.Empty;

    public MigrationTests()
    {
        _testDb = Path.Combine("C:\\", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.Replace(".", "") + ".sdf");

        if (File.Exists(_testDb))
            File.Delete(_testDb);

        _connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False;", _testDb);

        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ThrowsErrorForOutOfDateDatabase()
    {
        // The initializer will handle migrating the database. 
        // If ctor param is false, auto migration is off and an error will be throw saying the database is out of date.
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrationDatabaseInitializer<MethodObjectContext>(false));

        // Create the initial database and do a query.
        // This will create the database with the conventions of the Product1 type.
        TryQueryType<Product1>("Product");

        // The next query will create a new model that has conventions for the product2 type.
        // It has an additional property which makes the database (created from previous query) out of date.
        // An error should be thrown indicating that the database is out of sync.
        ExceptionAssert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => TryQueryType<Product2>("Product"));
    }

    private void TryQueryType<T>(string tableName) where T : class
    {
        using (var context = new MethodObjectContext(_connectionString, new FakeEventPublisher(x => x.ModelBuilder.Entity<T>().ToTable(tableName))))
        {
            var respository = new EfRepository<T>(context);
            var items = respository.Table.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My Product1 class is a POCO object, and my Product2 class is the same object with an additional db field.

My problem is that when I new() up the MethodObjectContext the second time and do a query, the ModelCreating method isn't called, causing me to get the following error.

```
The entity type Product2 is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Product2 would be a part of the context of the ModelCreating event was being called, but it is not. Any ideas?

NOTE: I am expecting errors since we are using the same connection string (sdf) and the db being created didn't create the additional field that my second call (Product2) requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My DbCompiledModel was being cached. The following flushed the cache.

```
private void ClearDbCompiledModelCache()
{
    var type = Type.GetType("System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext, EntityFramework");
    var cmField = type.GetField("CachedModels",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var cachedModels = cmField.GetValue(null);
    cachedModels.GetType().InvokeMember("Clear", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, cachedModels, null);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the caching is there for a reason. Building the model can be expensive and if it is done every time that the context is used then there may be perf issues with your app. A better approach would be to use the DbModelBuilder directly to create DbCompiledModels which you can then cache as appropriate. DbContext has constructors that accept a DbCompiledModel.